# Swift bind to Objective-C boolean value

Tags: macos, cocoa, swift

I've got a button `shuffleButton` that you can click to toggle shuffling.

Since I like to store that property when the app is closed I've bound a custom property `selected`, which is a Bool, from the `shuffleButton` to the user defaults.

```
shuffleButton.bind("selected", toObject: NSUserDefaultsController.sharedUserDefaultsController(), withKeyPath: "values.shuffle", options: nil)
```

This only works one way though. If I set the user default property the button updates.

```
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setValue(true, forKey: "shuffle")

// test it out
println(NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().valueForKey("shuffle"))
=> 1
println(shuffleButton.selected)
=> true
```

But if I update the `selected` property on the button the user default is not updated.

```
shuffleButton.selected = true

// test it out
println(NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().valueForKey("shuffle"))
=> 0
println(shuffleButton.selected)
=> true
```

Any idea why? Is the Swift Bool value not being bridged properly to Objective-C?

Answer (score 1):

Try using setBool to set bool value because bool is not an object,thats why iOS providing this method to save bool value.
You no need to bridge shuffleButton.selected will accept the swift bool value, everything is rewritten in swift language (check the class reference) following sample is working fine

```
    let defs = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults();
    var k = true;
    defs.setBool(k, forKey: "bool");
    defs.setDouble(2.5, forKey: "foo");
    defs.synchronize();
    var ud = defs.doubleForKey("foo");
       var bo = defs.boolForKey("bool");
    println("default = \(ud) bool =\(bo)");
    shuffleButton.selected = bo;
```

Answer (score 0):

When you update(Change Value) SuffleButton then also update your NSUserdefault.

```
  shuffleButton.selected = true

 NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(shuffleButton.selected as Bool!, forKey: "shuffle")
 NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
```

Comment: I know there are other ways to make this happen, but would prefer bindings in this situation.

Comment: shuffleButton.selected it's return a Bool Value.then u can typecasting this object and update your NSUserdefaults.i was update my answer.

Comment: u can also convert your value to objective-C value.like, let a:Double = firstText.text.bridgeToObjectiveC().doubleValue